# Firebase Cloud messaging to send only in-app messages for Webapp

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am successfully using FCM to send notification messages from my server, however I wanted to send certain messages only when the user has the app in foreground and display it using a toast and not show when app is in background. however , at my current attempt using a data object instead of notification object in my API post I still get a system notification, with message title as "Background Message Title, and Body as "Background Message body".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I ended up doing that worked was, add an `inAppOnly: true` flag to the data object of the FCM sent message. Then in the following function:

```
messaging.setBackgroundMessageHandler(payload => {
if (payload.data.inAppOnly === true) {
 return null
} else {
 return self.registration.showNotification(payload.data.Title,
    payload.data.Options)
}
})
```